# is it possible to consume multiple webservice into one main webservice?

Tags: wcf, web-services, web

I have a couple of webservices that i want to put into one main services and instead of having to reference multiple webservices i can just reference only one main webservice. is this is even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. As long as you've followed the standard practice of splitting your contract from your implementation, not only will it be possible, but easy too.

Just put them all into the same class, which implements all your contracts.

This obviously needs to reference all the contracts, but then you only need to use this service reference elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

Composition is a common pattern.

Yes, it is possible but not sure if it's ok from your architecture/product point of view. If your services must run in a single "transaction" then you might have to check if the compensation mechanisms are still in place in case that some step fails.